# Exlude folders from OpenSSH in Windows

Tags: windows-10, powershell, openssh, sftp

Is there a possibility to exclude folders (Windows 10 - OpenSSH-Server) from accessing it via SFTP?

Comment: Which application are you using?

Comment: @Burgi he mentioned OpenSSH server

Comment: @LPChip I rather stupidly thought he was talking about a client program that would exclude files.

Comment: @Burgi I just enabled the the (Windows build in) OpenSSH-Server with the Windows-PowerShell, so that it can be accessed with the IP-Adress via SFTP (this works), but via this method you get access to the entire PC. (As Client-Programm I use filezilla)